# Make wc -l work with path variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, bin

I need to take action depending on the number of lines in a file.
To make it dynamic i use variables with paths and files to use and pass everything to this if statement:

```
if [[ $(wc -l < $PATH) -gt 1 ]]
then
echo "File has more lines"
fi
```

When I execute the command with the `$PATH` I get a `wc: command not found` as output, when instead of `$PATH` I give it the path+filename it works.

It wouldn't be much of a problem for it to be static since the file should always be located in that spot and it is produced by a program, but now it is something I want to understand why it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash variable names should be `path` or `filename` instead of `PATH`, because PATH has a specific meaning.

Comment: Thank you, wasn't taking that into consideration: I saw variables being used all UPPERCASE and went with that without thinking.

Comment: In general, all-uppercase names are reserved by POSIX. Make sure you have at least one `_`, number, or lowercase character in your own names.